# How to fix "POST http://localhost:8000/users/create 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I'm setting on my "HTML", and I want to send data with JavaScript, but still receive the following error.

> 405 (Method Not Allowed)

**JavaScript**

```js
function cb(){

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'http://localhost:8000/users/create',
        data:selchbox,
    });

    var selchbox = [];
    var sb = [];
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i<input.length;i++){
        if (input[i].type == 'checkbox' && input[i].checked == true) 
            selchbox.push(input[i].value);
    }
    console.log(selchbox);
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::post('/create', 'usersController@create');
```

Comment: Its something else but worth mentioning(Also it might be the error causer) : You can't send POST requests without `CSRF` token : `https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf`

Comment: Does your route have any prefix ?

Comment: Depending on your laravel version, you want to add a method "PUT" in your ajax. Also make sure Laravel is using the CSRF token in the ajax request.

Answer (score 2):

You're POSTing to `/users/create`, but your route definition is for plain old `/create`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you are calling a route named /users/create instead of /create

You may also need to do this since laravel does not allow any request without the auto generated csrf token.You can set your csrf token to the html meta like this.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And call it in JavaScript like this.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: '/your_route',
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')                                                                                                                                                                                                
     },
     data,
 }).done(results => {
     //results                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 })
```

Comment: Lacking a CSRF token will throw a TokenMismatchException, not a 405. OP may *also* need to fix this, but it's not the cause of their stated issue.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thats true I updated my answer to address this.